# Easiest way to test a list of URLS for 404?

Tags: microsoft-excel, url, http-status-code-404

If i have a list of URLS (a column in excel), what is the easiest way to test all of them for 404? Currently, I just have to click each one, look at the page, and close the tab/window, and this is a pain.

Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way will be to use a software solution built for the job https://www.excelurlvalidator.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted [quite a good VBA solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118221/sort-dead-hyperlinks-in-excel-with-vba) over on Stack Overflow.

Comment: that does exactly what I originally wanted. Unfortunately, turns out, I don't actually need to look for 404s. I'm using this on sharepoint sites, which doesn't return a 404 for sites not configured, but instead displays a page that says "The Web site that is referenced here is not in the configuration database." - so I'll need to find an alternate solution and potentially ask a new question.

Comment: @xdumaine pretty sure you could just script that with wget and grep for your new requirements.

Comment: @darren this was on Windows, using SharePoint and excel, 6 years ago. But thanks.

Comment: @xdumaine oh, haha. I didn’t look at the date. It got bumped to the top of the question list for some reason. I assumed it was new.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large number of Excel Sheets that contains URLs,You can use this Desktop software **Excel Url Validator** to validate URLs and find broken links.The software can automatically find URLs from a Bunch of Excel Spreadshets,Validate the links and produce Individual Reports for Each file processed.You can download it from http://excelurlvalidator.com

Disclaimer: I represent the Company that develops the product.